# Find a text string from a long list of options and return a value depending on said option

Tags: google-sheets

I have been trying several solutions suggested in diverse fora for a few hours but nothing seems to work (see [here](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Formulas-and-Functions/HOW-TO-quot-If-cell-contains-specific-text-then-return-specific/m-p/69802#M630), for example).
So this is my problem:

- I have a long column of text strings which contain some keywords and lots of rubbish.
- I would like to generate a new clean value in another column, depending on which one of the keywords were found in the first one.
- I have a little table with the keywords/strings to be found and the desired return values.
- I have tried nested IFs, but it becomes too complex and not flexible. I would prefer a function that relies on that table.

Comment: Adding some sample data to your question would probably be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keyword table: Z1:Z4
Text strings: A:A

B1:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXEXTRACT(A:A,JOIN("|",Z1:Z4)))
```

Comment: Worked like a charm :-)  Thank you very much!  This is sufficient to solve my problem. But in case I wanted an output value that is not exactly the keyword in Z1:Z4, but a corresponding term in Y1:Y4, how could I do that?